# Imagem não está aparecendo na página (não está sendo encontrada)

Tags: javascript, html, react, next.js, jsx

Oi, preciso de ajuda, estou usando create-next-app e a imagem que estou tentando colocar na página **index** não está sendo encontrada, aqui está o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui a organização das pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei o que está acontecendo, já tentei colocar o path da imagem direto no atributo src="" e já tentei usar require() ao invés de import.

No navegador:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

**Importe o componente de imagem:**

```
import Image from 'next/image'
```

**E então utilize normalmente, assim como a tag Img:**

```
<Image
  src={logo}
  alt="Logo"
/>
```

**Você encontra mais informações sobre esse componente da documentação do Nextjs**